# setting the hql or criteria for the below sql with decode condition in sql

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have the below following pojo and I have to generate the hql or criteria  for the following sql..

```
class took
{
 private String aaa;
 private String bbb = "";
 private String ccc;


public took(String aaa, String bbb ,String ccc)
    {
    this.aaa = aaa;
    this.bbb = bbb;
    this.ccc = ccc;     
    }
}

SELECT aaa,DECODE(bbb_b,'Y','Act','Rev') as perm,ccc_c FROM took
```

I have also generated the HQL for this as shown below , but the issue with this query is that as shown in the above sql query that I am using DECODE on column bbb_b and setting it value plus this column perm is created dynamically in this query itself so how would I adjust this in hql itself
please advise.

```
List<took> b1 = session.createQuery("select new com.abc.def.took(aaa, bbb,ccc) from took").list();
```

please advise for crtiteria equivalent for this

Answer (score 0):

You can add this annotation to your bbb property (if you use annotations).

```
@Formula("DECODE(bbb_b,'Y','Act','Rev')")
public String getBbb() {
   return bbb;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot also advise that the HQL would be the same as I have shown above please advise

Comment: Just add this annotation to your property. HQL should be fine.

Comment: also please advise my application is mostly using hibernate 3 but mostly configured in xml so in hibernate 3 can I add this annotation in pojo itself

Comment: any way to achieve same through criteria please advise

Comment: Here is for xml mapping (if use XML, modify XML only): http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-column

Comment: any way to achieve through criteria

Comment: You could try to use this for criteria instead: Projections.sqlProjection(sql, columnAliases, types)

Comment: @Formula is the easiest way.

Comment: thanks a lot due to some limitation I have to go for criteria could you please post the updated query for criteria , that will be a great help thanks a lot

Comment: Also you can use createSQLQuery("SELECT aaa,DECODE(bbb_b,'Y','Act','Rev') as perm,ccc_c FROM took");

Comment: Create SQL query is i am already using pls advise for criteria

Comment: please advise for criteria Thanks in advance